# WebApp and iOS App which access the same Database

Tags: c#, objective-c, database, visual-studio-2015, xcode8

This question may not belong here, and if so, if you could instead point me in the right direction as apposed to marking me down, it would be much appreciated. However, I figured that these Forums are as good a place as any to come to for some advice.

Anyway, here's a simple description of what it is I hope to achieve and the questions that I have.

For a Project I'm working on, I have proposed to create a WebApp, using MS Visual Studio, and an iOS App, using Xcode, both of which need to access a central Database.

Initially, all I want to achieve is for a User of the WebApp to be able to add, edit and delete data, and for a User of the iOS App to be able to view this data.

I basically just want some advice on the best way to go about creating a suitable Database, and if there are any available resources you guys feel would be of benefit to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, it sounds like what you are looking for is an Web Service layer, hosted on some sort of server and backed by some sort of database  that can be accessed by both your web front-end and your iOS front end. There are about a billion frameworks for doing that. Basically, pick a language, OS, and database and get started. Your question is pretty broad for StackOverflow, but basically Google these terms:
Relational Database, HTTP, Web Service, REST, Web Framework, and Service Layer and go from there, and maybe look for more help at the Programmers Stack Exchange.

Comment: Going to be using C# and Objective C but just unsure of how to go about creating the Database. Thanks for the advice though. @NickBailey

Answer (score 0):

As you looks like Microsoft product lover, you can also use Xamarin for iOS app development which using c# as basic development language which helps you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.